# Difference between star formation rate and star formation history

Tags: astrophysics, terminology, stars, galaxies, stellar-evolution

When we speak about galaxies evolution, what is the difference between the star formation rate and the star formation history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The star formation history is the function "Star formation rate" as function of time.